# How to change a variable that is stated in a parameter

Tags: javascript

I wanted to shorten up my code by being able to change a variable that is listed in the parameters. What I mean by this is being able change which variable is being changed by the function. How can I do this in the shortest way possible?

Current HTML and JS:

```
<script src="test.js"> </script>
<p onclick="TEST(this, test)"></p>
```

.

```
var test= 0;
function TEST(element, value){
element.innerHTML = value
value= 1;
}
```

Comment: in javascript everything is passed by value. there is no pass by reference.

Comment: One way to do it is to pass the string name of the variable, and resolve it from its current scope via square brackets (ie. `global.$` is the same as `global['$']`). That's pretty much the only way, but it depends on knowing in what scope the variable is declared (ie. `global` or `window` or `document` or whatever).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in javascript everything is passed by value. there is no pass by reference.

You can pass an object and change properties on that.

```
var test= { value: 0 };
function TEST(element, value){
  element.innerHTML = value
  value.value= 1;
}
```